# Regular travel between UK and Belgium as an Irish citizen + tax?

Tags: belgium, brexit, common-travel-area

I am an Irish citizen, my partner is Belgian. We have been living together in Ireland for several years.

For work I need to move to the UK in a few months, where I will be employed for about 3 years. I will need to be a resident for tax purposes. Our original plan involved my partner moving to the UK with me, but when we discovered visa costs, we decided she'd go back to Belgium instead and I would visit for a few days each week (covid restrictions allowing).

We do worry about the frequent travel/tax residency/double taxation, etc. As an Irish citizen, I won't need a UK visa, so I'm hoping weekly travel will not be an issue. I also don't plan to register as a resident in Belgium, since I won't stay continuously for very long.

Anyone have experience with this, post-Brexit? Any tips on what to do/avoid would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't have experience with tax rules of these specific jurisdictions, but in general as long as you spend more than half of your time in the jurisdiction where you work (the UK) you won't be considered a tax resident anywhere else.  You are correct that (ignoring public health restrictions) travel will not be an issue.  Your partner should also be able to spend a liberal amount of time in the UK, in theory, provided that she spends less than half of her time there.  For concerns raised by frequent visits to the UK, see [Travel.SE].

Comment: Good grief, how expensive is that visa? You're taking on a load of expenses in money (double household, train/plane tickets), time (weekly international trips), and quality of life (living apart).